# Illegal string offset 'key'

Tags: php, json, rest

I have this code:

```
// Champion name and splash art
$endpointChampion = file_get_contents("https://global.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/static-data/BR/v1.2/champion/".$championMastery."?api_key=MYKEY");
$jsonChampion = json_decode($endpointChampion, true);

foreach ($jsonChampion as $champion) {  
    if (isset($jsonChampion['key'])) {
        $championKey = $champion['key'];
    }
}
```

But this $championKey variable returns "o" and 3 warnings are prompted on screen:

*Warning: Illegal string offset 'key' in E:\xampp\htdocs\riot\index.php on line 41*

I also tried to validate the entry, using `isset()` but seems not work properly.

The $championMastery is retrieved here:

```
$endpointMastery = file_get_contents("https://br.api.riotgames.com/championmastery/location/BR1/player/8083198/champions?api_key=MYKEY");
$jsonMastery = json_decode($endpointMastery, true);

foreach ($jsonMastery as $mastery) {
    $championMastery = $mastery['championId'];
    $masteryLevel = $mastery['championLevel'];
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why are you switching between `$jsonChampion` and `$champion`?

Comment: `isset($jsonChampion['key'])` need to be `isset($champion['key'])`

Comment: print the output of `$jsonChampion` and show us

Comment: The foreach loop is totally unnecessary, thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams for the light. I just remove it and set $championKey = $jsonChampion['key'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error because API returns one dimensional array and `$champion` is string value in `foreach ($jsonChampion as $champion)`. Following can be fix:

```
foreach ($jsonChampion as $champion) {
      if (isset($jsonChampion['key'])) {
          $championKey = $jsonChampion['key'];
      }
}
```

BTW,
`$jsonChampion` is one dimensional Array so you can retrieve `$championKey` without writing foreach loop as follows:

```
if(is_array($jsonChampion) && isset($jsonChampion['key'])){
      $championKey = $jsonChampion['key'];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized now. Can I read more values without using this foreach? Inside this if i mean.

Comment: Based on your scenerio, If it is one dimensional array then you don't need to write foreach loop. You can access value by array['key']